# Using python ftp server all get and put commands time out

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp, python

In Debian, I'm running python's ftp server (from the command line -- not in a code project) as so:

```
python -m pyftpdlib -w -p21
```

On a Windows 2008 server, I run:

```
ftp <IP>
user:  anonymous
pass:  anonymous
```

Which returns:

```
230 Login successful.
```

But when I do a get or put, it times out with:

```
421 Active data channel timeout.
```

On the Windows box, Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Advanced tab -> Use Passive FTP is unchecked!

On Windows, I've also run `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off` just to make sure the firewall wasn't causing the problem

Any thoughts on how to I can get `put` and `get` to work?

Comment: Firewall on the debian system or between the two?

Comment: Use passive FTP at the client. While it does not help in all cases it usually causes far fewer trouble than active FTP. Apart from that FTP is a protocol which is known to cause trouble if firewalls and/or NAT are involved in the connection.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Hmmm... UI cannot send the pasv command -- it's not recoginized.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes Windows Firewall is configured on the 2008 R2 box.  I did set the profile states to off and disable it.  No change.

Comment: What about the debian systems firewall?

Comment: Are you sure pyftpdlib can do active ftp?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille... the Linux firewall isn't running and the pyftpdlib documentation says it need to run in ACTV.

Comment: "netsh advfireall set allprofiles state off"  seems to contain a typo.